# Pausing a storyboard on TabItem mouse over

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a tab control with invisible tabs.

when you mouse over a certain area of my form, it calls my c# handler which runs:

`((Storyboard)FindResource("animate")).Begin(HiddenTab);`

The animate storyboard:

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="animate">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:2.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:5.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <Visibility>Hidden</Visibility>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

Now what I want to do is pause the animation when the mouse is over the tab item, and resume the animation when the mouse leaves the tab item.

I applied `EventSetter`s to my tab items via a controltemplate to call:

`((Storyboard)FindResource("animate")).Pause(HiddenTab);`

But it says it cannot find `animate` within my TabItem ControlTemplate, which makes sense since `animate` is defined as a window resource.

How can I get access to the storyboard so i can pause/resume?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code to access resource in wpf

```
Object res1 = this.Resources["animate"];
```

type cast it to story board and see if it helps.

Comment: Unable to perform action because the specified Storyboard was never applied to this object for interactive control.; Action='Pause'; Storyboard='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard'

Comment: no, the storyboard is not linked to the `ControlTemplate` of a `TabItem` in any way. I am using the animation by calling `((Storyboard)FindResource("animate")).Begin(HiddenTab)`